# bloginfo no show the right path

Tags: urls, paths

I use  bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) for show the link to css styles , in localhost in my computer i can see the url right as `http://127.0.0.1 , etc`

The problem it´s inside of domain , i see the DOM and see that no show http:// only show domain.com and by this no let me the css load , if i add http:// until of this function works all and if no , no works

Why in localhost show http and inside domain this function give the url without http ?

In my options all it´s ok with http i don´t know what happend really , thank´s , Regards !!!

I use these 2 functions :

```
bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ); 
get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

the codex says [get_stylesheet_directory_uri();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) returns a properly-formed URI; in other words, it will be a web-address (starting with http:// or https:// for SSL). As such.

i don't understand why it's not working for you, try to use [get_template_directory_uri();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) in the event a child theme is being used, the parent theme directory URI will be returned, get_template_directory_uri() should be used for resources that are not intended to be included in/over-ridden by a child theme.